# different color for every item of flatlist based on condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want color of every item based on condition like:-

[image]

I will have my condition like :- `let check = item.project_status`.

and `check` can be completed, in-progress and incomplete.

and red for incomplete, yellow for in-progress and green for completed.

Here is my flatlist code:-

```
  <FlatList
        style={{height:constants.DesignHeight - 100}}
            data={props.DATA}
            renderItem={({ item }) =>
            
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={props.onPress} style={styles.flatlistContainer}>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.project_name}  </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text2}>Start: {moment(item.start_date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between'  }}>
                        <Text style={styles.text}>Assigned to: {item.project_manager.name}  </Text>
                        <Text style={styles.text2}>End: {moment(item.end_date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>

                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            }
            KeyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
           // ItemSeparatorComponent={() => renderSeparator()}
        />

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
flatlistContainer: {
    width: '100%',
},
text: {
    fontSize: constants.vw(20),
    lineHeight: constants.vw(30),
},

text2: {
    fontSize: constants.vw(16),
    lineHeight: constants.vw(30),
}
```

})

How can I achieve this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: *'...red for incomplete, yellow for in-progress and green for completed'* where exactly are those statuses stored?

Comment: in item.project_status

Comment: Which exactly part of above JSX you need to style? I'm asking because I'm struggling to make connection between your screenshot and what your code seems to render.

Comment: Sorry I copied wrong code, check now

Comment: What is it exactly do you use for styling? What `styles.text` is referring to?

Comment: I have added styles too.

Comment: You seem to be looking for something, like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707327/passing-props-into-external-stylesheet-in-react-native)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you can make a style for each project status
and you can use it

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
...
incomplete: {
  color: 'red'
},
inprogress: {
  color: 'yellow'
},
completed: {
  color: 'green'
}
}})
```

and you can use it on style tag
like this

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'space-between' }}>
      <Text style={[styles.text, styles[item.project_status]}>{item.project_name}  </Text>
      <Text style={[styles.text2, styles[item.project_status]}>Start: {moment(item.start_date).format("DD/MM/YYYY")}</Text>
</View>
```