# React native StyleSheet.create where should I put

Tags: react-native, react-native-stylesheet

I need to pass props into Styles. So I created StyleSheet inside the class. But normal practice would be to create StyleSheet outside from the class.

I want to know are there any performance drawbacks by having `StyleSheet.create` inside the class ?

```
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { Text } from 'native-base'
import p from '../../assets/colors/pallets'

const EmptyContainer = (props) => {
  const texts = props.texts

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    emptyContainer: {
      flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      padding: 20,
      backgroundColor: p.background2[props.theme],
    },
    text: {
      color: p.text1[props.theme],
    },
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.emptyContainer}>
      {texts.map((text) => (
        <Text style={styles.text} key={Math.random()}>
          {text}
        </Text>
      ))}
    </View>
  )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { theme } = state

  return {
    theme: theme.theme,
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmptyContainer)
```

Edited:
There are several ways to pass props into StyleSheet.

1. Having `StyleSheet` inside class itself.
2. Pass props as function parameter to styles i.e. `styles(props.theme). emptyContainer`

What would be the best way by considering the performance of the app ?

Comment: similar to your query https://stackoverflow.com/a/51123464/9444013

Comment: @shammi yes, but it does not answer my question exactly. I want to know are there any performance drawbacks using this method. `styles(this.props).icon` passing like this also possible, but in that case styles is working as function and are there any performance drawbacks ?

Comment: if you want to not lose performance then you can use inline style

Comment: @shammi If you use objects or arrays for styling (inline style), they will create new instances with each new render. You should use a StyleSheet in React Native, the advantage is in this way always passes a reference instead of a new object or array creation and allocation.