# How to pass a variable to React Native Stylesheet?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I want to pass a variable to the "shadowColor" property in my stylesheet from an array in the code above but I am getting a "Can't find name " error. I tried to use a template literal but it's not working. Any help is appreciated!

```
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, Image } from "react-native";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { LinearGradient } from "expo-linear-gradient";

export default function Card(props: any) {
  const colors = [
    ["#FE90B0", "#F45283", "#ff0047"],
    ["#89E5FE", "#43C5E9", "#00c9ff"],
    ["#AE9CFF", "#927FFC", "#2700ff"],
    ["#FED3A0", "#FFA741", "#ff8800"],
  ];
  return (
    <View
      style={[styles.card, styles.shadow, { shadowColor: `${colors[0][2]}` }]}
    >
      // .... unrelated code
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  card: {
    height: "33%",
    width: "85%",
    borderRadius: 35,
  },
  shadow: {
    shadowColor: `${colors[0][2]}`,
    shadowOffset: {
      width: 0,
      height: 18,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 20.0,
    elevation: 24,
  },
  fonts: {
    padding: 15,
  },
  img: {
    width: "100%",
    height: "95%",
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this is happening is because you declare you `colors` variable inside of your `Card` component, but you try to *use* your `colors` variable *outside* of your `Card`'s scope.  There are several solutions, depending on what you want to do:

1. Lift the `colors` variable up and make it a module-scoped array:

   ```js
   const colors = [
     ["#FE90B0", "#F45283", "#ff0047"],
     ["#89E5FE", "#43C5E9", "#00c9ff"],
     ["#AE9CFF", "#927FFC", "#2700ff"],
     ["#FED3A0", "#FFA741", "#ff8800"],
   ];

   export default function Card(props: any) { /* ... snip ... */ }

   const styles = StyleSheet.create({ /* ... snip ... */ });
   ```
2. Use the technique described in [the question @Odunsi linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42707327/passing-props-into-external-stylesheet-in-react-native) to pass the selected values into your `StyleSheet.create` call:

   ```js
   const stylesFor = colors => StyleSheet.create({ /* ... snip ... */ });
   export default function Cards(props: any) {
     return <View style={stylesFor(colors).SOME_CLASS} />;
   }
   ```